# Rebuilding a signal using the fast fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I've created a signal by adding a sine wave and a cosine wave using `R`:

```
# number of samples
N <- 1000    

# time period
TT <- 2       

# sampling frequency (number of samples by unit of time)
fs <- N / TT  

# vector of sampling time points
stp <- seq(from=0, to=TT - 1 / fs, by=1 / fs)

# 2 Hz sine wave with peak amplitude 2
sn1 <- 2 * sin(2 * pi * 2 * stp)

# 5 Hz cosine wave with peak amplitude 3
sn2 <- 3 * cos(2 * pi * 5 * stp)

# input signal
sn <- sn1 + sn2
```

[image]

Using the Fourier transform, I can see that the signal is made up of two waves with amplitudes 2 and 3 and frequencies 2 and 5, respectively.

```
fou <- fft(sn)
N <- length(fou)
fou <- fou[2:((N / 2) + 1)]
freq <- (1:(N / 2)) / TT
ampl <- Mod(fou) / length(fou)
plot(freq, ampl)
```

[image]

**Question**:
How do I know that the wave with frequency 2 is a *sine wave* and that the wave with frequency 5 is a *cosine wave*?

Comment: You've plotted the amplitude: `ampl <- Mod(fou) / length(fou)`, if you want to distinguish between a sine and a cosine you also need to look at the *phase* plot. Regarding the 'reconstruction', have you tried just using an inverse FFT? e.g. http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/signal/html/ifft.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sine and Cosine are the same wave shifted by $\pi/2$ in phase $$\cos(x)=\sin(x+\pi/2)$$. Fourier transform returns you a complex number for each frequency. This number has the amplitude and the angle (phase). It's basically a set of Sine waves with amplitudes and phases. Equivalently, you can [re-write them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms) as a sum of Sine and Cosine waves of different amplitudes.

Example:

```
phase <- Arg(fou) 
sx=ampl[4]*cos(2*pi*freq[4]*stp+phase[4])+ampl[10]*cos(2*pi*freq[10]*stp+phase[10])
plot(sx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you further help me to rebuild the signal above using the output of fft()?

Comment: You got the frequency already. All you need is a phase, which is an angle of the complex number.

Comment: Thanks :-) Last thing: why do you use cosines in 'sx' rather than sines?

Comment: Try sines, but you'll have to add $\pi/2$ to the phase. It's just the way sinces and cosines are add up in FFT.

Comment: Perfect :-) (+1)